# In model my image field is showing blank even though I have inserted the image from html

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

[In model my image field is showing blank even though I have inserted the image from html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxkKb.png)

Comment: please provide models.py views.py admin.py and settings.py

Answer (score 1):

Show your code. Once the `views.py`, the `models.py` and your `html`. Here are my two best guesses:

1 verify you have the `enctype` declared in the html  tag

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

2 verify you request includes `request.FILES`

```
form = YourForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
```